# How to accept array of class type as parameter

Tags: swift

I'd like to pass an array of class types as parameter to a function, how can I do that?

Code:

```
let classList = [Class1.self, Class2.self, Class3.self]
myFunction(classList)    // how would I write the parameter for this?
```

Goal:
I created a `UITableView` extension to shorten registering nibs and you can call it using `tableView.register(CellClass.self)`. The function signature is `func register<T>(_ cellType: T.Type)`

Given that, I'm trying to create a register cells function where I want to do something like this:

```
func registerCells(classTypes: [XXXX]) {
     classTypes { (classType) in
        tableView.register(YYYY)
     }
}
```

and call it using `tableView.resigterCells([Class1.self, Class2.self, Class3.self])`

I'm not sure if this is possible in Swift. Please advise :)

Comment: AnyClass exists, but Swift does not really want you to pass class types around. What is the real goal here? There is probably a much better way.

Comment: @matt I updated my question to tell what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Aren't you better off with `[UITableViewCell.Type]`, then?

Comment: That's a much better question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do this:

```
func registerOneCellType(_ type: UITableViewCell.Type) {}
func registerCellTypes(_ types:[UITableViewCell.Type]) {
    for type in types {
        registerOneCellType(type)
    }
}
class CellType1: UITableViewCell {}
class CellType2: UITableViewCell {}
registerCellTypes([CellType1.self, CellType2.self])
```

But you know something? I wouldn't! I would pass actual cell objects and take their type and go from there.  Swift is a lot more pleasant when you pass instances rather than types.

```
func registerOneType(ofCell: UITableViewCell) {}
func registerTypes(ofCells: [UITableViewCell]) {
    for cell in ofCells {
        registerOneType(ofCell: cell)
    }
}
class CellType1: UITableViewCell {}
class CellType2: UITableViewCell {}
registerTypes(ofCells: [CellType1(), CellType2()])
```

Inside `registerOneType` I would call `type(of:)` to get the type, and off you go. Note that you don't need a generic here (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to put any class type into the array, then you need to use `[AnyObject.Type]` as a type.

Here's the example

```
class A { }
class B { }
class C { }

let elms: [AnyObject.Type] = [A.self, B.self, C.self]

func foo(elms: [AnyObject.Type]) {
    print(elms)
}

foo(elms: elms)
```

Answer (score 1):

`AnyClass` is type alias for `AnyObject.Type`. That means that it's a metatype which can hold any '`classtype`'

```
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}

let classList : [AnyClass] = [A.self, B.self, C.self]

 perfornAction(classList)
```

Then function can be written as

```
func perfornAction(_ list:[AnyClass]) { 
        if let abc = list[0] as? A.Type{
            print("A")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know all your classes will be subclasses of `UITableViewCell`, I would suggest saying so in your code:

```swift
class X: UITableViewCell {}
class Y: UITableViewCell {}
class Z: UITableViewCell {}

func registerCells(classTypes: [UITableViewCell.Type]) {
    classTypes.forEach {
        tableView.register($0, forCellReuseIdentifier: "foo")
    }
}

registerCells(classTypes: [X.self, Y.self, Z.self])
```